# Returning null in a function that should return an integer

Tags: java, data-structures, null

The code identifies the integer that is closest to 0 in an array and if there are 2 or more values that meet this condition the return value should be null.The problem is that when I make the condition to return null it displays an error because the function is supposed to return an integer.

```
    static int function(int [] arr){
    int closest=arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(Math.abs(arr[i])<closest){
            arr[i]=closest;
        }
        else if(arr[i]==closest){
            return null;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

I am very new to Java (learned Python before),if there is a better/more eficient approach to this code please share.

Comment: use `Integer` as the return type

Comment: Just wondering, why would you want to return `null` when there are more than 1 match? Both are them are technically equally close. Also take note, you didn't handle the case where there is a `-1` and `1` for example, where both are equally close (since you used `Math.abs()`). Furthermore, you have done the assignment in the wrong direction (`arr[i]=closest;` should be `closest=arr[i];`). Lastly, you didn't consider what happens when you have stored a negative number in the `if()` comparison statement.

Comment: It is a programming challenge on Codewars and that is what the instructions said haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* convert the return type to `Integer` which can hold `null` and will auto box and unbox to an int:

```
static Integer function(int [] arr){
    int closest=arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(Math.abs(arr[i])<closest){
            arr[i]=closest;
        }
        else if(arr[i]==closest){
            return null;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

However this is probably not the best solution. You could instead return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to signify that two of the elements were equidistant from zero. This depends on how you plan to handle the case where there are two elements of equal distance to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to support `null` (e.g. Python's `None`) then you should return the wrapper type `Integer`.

```
static Integer function(int [] arr) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is to return `Integer` instead of `int`.

```
static Integer function(int[] arr) {
```

Autoboxing will take care of wrapping the primitive; autounboxing will take care of giving your client code `NullPointerException`.

But you said efficient, but allocating a genuine object is not efficient (small values will use a common object, but that still isn't great). Throwing an exception would be even less efficient (supposing it happens frequently enough.)

The routine could perhaps return any `int` value and we want to shove in an extra possible outcode. So one possibility is to go one larger and return a `long` with `Long.MIN_VALUE` as the special value. May require casting on the client code to get back to an `int`.

```
static Integer function(int[] arr) {
```

`Long.MIN_VALUE` is interesting in that `Long.MIN_VALUE == Math.abs(Long.MIN_VALUE)`.

It's at this point we realise there's appears to be a bug in the code (not sure as I really know what it is supposed to be doing).

```
    if(Math.abs(arr[i])<closest){
```

This is always true for `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Probably you want to swap that around with.

```
    if (-Math.abs(arr[i]) > -closest){
```

Converting to `long` before doing the comparison is also possible but less clever. (Integer overflows - bleurgh.)

Another way around the problem is to let the client code choose an appropriate value to signal the same as whatever `null` is supposed to indicate.

```
static int function(int[] arr, int dflt) {
    [...]
        } else if (arr[i] == closest) {
            return dflt;
        [...]
```